# S3distcp on local hadoop cluster not working

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, s3distcp

**I am trying to run s3distcp from my local hadoop pseudo cluster. As a result of executing s3distcp.jar i received the following stack-trace . It seems that reducer task is failing but I am not able to pinpoint the reason which could be causing reducer to fail :-**

```
18/02/21 12:14:01 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local639263089_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Reducer task failed to copy 1 files: file:/home/chirag/workspaces/lzo/data-1518765365022.lzo etc
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:556)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Reducer task failed to copy 1 files: file:/home/chirag/workspaces/lzo/data-1518765365022.lzo etc
    at com.amazon.external.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.CopyFilesReducer.close(CopyFilesReducer.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:346)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/02/21 12:14:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local639263089_0001 running in uber mode : false
18/02/21 12:14:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
18/02/21 12:14:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local639263089_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
18/02/21 12:14:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 35
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error. In my case, I found logs in HDFS /var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps/hadoop/logs related to the MR job that s3-dist-cp kicks off.

```
hadoop fs -ls /var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps/hadoop/logs
```

I copied them out to local:

```
hadoop fs -get /var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps/hadoop/logs/application_nnnnnnnnnnnnn_nnnn/ip-nnn-nn-nn-nnn.ec2.internal_nnnn
```

And then examined them in a text editor to find more diagnostic information about the detailed results of the Reducer phase. In my case I was getting an error back from the S3 service. You might find a different error.